Enum item: subitem immediately follows the item
How can I make the enumitem setlist setting so that the subitem that immediately follows the item aligns with the other subitems?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
    label=(\alph*),
    wide=0pt,
}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=(\roman*),
    wide=20pt,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kant[1][1]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \kant[2][1]
    \end{enumerate}
    \item \begin{enumerate}
        \item \item \kant[3][1]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}



Is it only for testing or are you going to have empty lists? You could append before={\vphantom{~}}, to settings of the inner list.

Some math papers (for example IB) has questions in that format. It is not something out of curiosity.

It turns out lists cannot be empty. In order to force new line after an item without content, you can add an invisible zero-length character before every list. This can be done with \vphantom{~}: \vphantom{} produce "contents" without consuming space for the content meaning anything afterwards will overlap it, and ~ in LaTeX is a non-breakable space.
before={<code>}, "injects" code before every list. Combining the option and \vphantom{~}} should work, at least in this specific case.
Here's the code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{
    label=(\alph*),
    wide=0pt,
}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{
    label=(\roman*),
    wide=20pt,
    before={\vphantom{~}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \kant[1][1]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \kant[2][1]
    \end{enumerate}
    \item \begin{enumerate}
        \item \item \kant[3][1]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


